# Ngrx store how to clear or reset all the state after the user has logged out in the App properly

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I use [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) **store** and **effect** for a better state management library since I am developing a large application. Every data flow is working fine and smooth. But there is one little problem.

If the user has logged out in the **App** some of the **states** related to a **session** or **user info** are **cleared** but what I want to happen is **clear** all the **states** from every **reducer**.

How will I achieve this? Here is something what I did below:

in my **actions-events.ts**

```
export const LOGOUT_REQUEST = 'LOGOUT_REQUEST';
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS';
export const LOGOUT_FAILED = 'LOGOUT_FAILED';
```

and in my **component.ts**

```
logout() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_REQUEST })
  }
```

in my **effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
    deAuthenticate$ = this.actions$.ofType(authActions.LOGOUT_REQUEST)
        .pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                return this.authApi.signOut().pipe(
                    map((response: any) => ({ type: authActions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS, payload: response })),
                    catchError(error => of({ type: authActions.LOGOUT_FAILED, payload: error }))
                )
            })
        )
```

I declared three types of actions that will be asynchronous on the first block of code. Then the component will dispatch an `LOGOUT_REQUEST` action. After that the **effects** will listen to that action and call a **method** on the **provider** to request an **http logout request** on a **server**. I will wait for the response and dispatch a **SUCCESS** or **FAILED** action to update the state tree.

Now everything is working fine but I notice that there is a little problem that some **data** exist or persist in the **store** or some part of the **state**. Which I don't want to happen when another user tries to logged in.

What I want to happen is clear all the whole state tree when a user logs out. How can I do that?

For additional information about my structure here is my **authReducer below**

```
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_FAILED, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_REQUEST, LOGOUT_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_FAILED } from './../actions/authenticate';
import { AuthState } from './../store';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { PostState } from '../store';

const initialState: AuthState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticating: false,
    unauthenticating: false,
    token: null,
    error: null
}

export function authReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST: // Sign in request
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticating: true,
            }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS: // Sign in success
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticating: false,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                token: (<any>action).payload.data.token
            }
        case LOGIN_FAILED: // Sign in failed
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticating: false,
                error: (<any>action).payload
            }
        case LOGOUT_REQUEST: // Sign out request
            return {
                ...state,
                unauthenticating: true
            }
        case LOGOUT_SUCCESS: // Signout success
            return {
                ...state,
                unauthenticating: false,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                token: null
            }
        case LOGOUT_FAILED: // Signout failed
            return {
                ...state,
                unauthenticating: false,
                error: (<any>action).payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and in my **rootReducer**

```
import { postsReducer } from "../reducers/posts";
import { usersReducer } from "./users";
import { authReducer } from "./authenticate";

export const rootReducer = {
    posts: postsReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
}
```

in my **app.module.ts** I used a logger for logging the state tree.

```
export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): any {
  // default, no options
  return storeLogger()(reducer);
}

export const metaReducers = [logger];
```

and in the **imports**

```
StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 15
    }),
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a reset action which is handled in your reducer as in:

```
case 'RESET'
  return initial state;
```

If you need this behavior in multiple reducers, I would suggest to use a meta-reducer as in:

[image]

Comment: I created a reducer like this `import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RESET_STATE } from '../actions/resetState';

export function resetStateReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>) {
    return function (state: any, action: any) {
        if (action.type == RESET_STATE) {
            state = undefined
        }
        return reducer(state, action)
    }
}` so it would reset the whole state tree and I will always dispatch this action after a logout_success right?

Comment: Yep, that should be it.